# InfoPath filler client not opening

Tags: 2013, infopath, ie

My comapny is using IE9, and some users have access to Mozilla (not many).

The environment is Office 2010 with Sharepoint 2013 Standard license. Infopath Filler 2010 and Designer 2010 are on the local machine.

I have created a forms library, and I am positive it is set to open with CLIENT APPLICATION.

The problem arises when you select +New Document. Both browsers attempt to access "ms-infopath:nft|u|http://spintranet/sites/workflows/PurchaseReqForm/forms/template.xsn|s|http://spintranet/sites/workflows/PurchaseReqForm"

IE9 returns "webpage cannot be displayed" Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you do not have installed.

FF returns Firefox doesnt know how to open this address, because on of the following protocols (ms-infopath) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

My thoughts are that because I'm using SP2013 with office 2010 this could be the issue.
I know nothing about Infopath, so I think there might be some option somewhere I might not be enabling?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a known issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2888015

Scenario 1

To work around this issue, remove the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support program component from the Office 2013 installation on the affected computer or computers. To do this, follow the “Install or remove individual Office program components” section of the following Microsoft Office website:

Install or remove individual Office programs and components

After you complete these steps, repair 2007 Office. For more information about how to repair the installation, click the following article number to go to the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:

924611 How to install the individual 2007 Office features or to repair the installed 2007 Office programs

Note When you follow these steps, set the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support component within Office Tools to Not Available. This solution doesn't apply to scenarios in which SharePoint Designer 2013 is installed on the affected computer.

Scenario 2

To resolve this issue, install Service Pack 2 for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2687455) on the affected computer. For more information about Service Pack 2 for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2687455), go to the following Microsoft website:
Service Pack 2 for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2687455) 32-Bit Edition

Comment: service pack 2 is installed on office 2010. Are you saying I should uninstall 2013 and then run a repair on office 2010? I still need sharepoint designer though.